# Javascript Regex not matching

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Essentially I am having problems with creating a regex for a list such as :

```
1. Eccentric Shop Teacher                                                       20M+         Good              EST
2. Wanwood Crown                                                                  18M+          Low                WWC
3. Domino Crown                                                                      16M+         Great              DC
4. Dominus Empyreus                                                              16M+         Great              Emp
```

The regex I am using : `(\d+.\s)([\w\'\s\d])([\d\w\+])`

Which only matches :

- 1: "1. "
- 2: "E"
- 3: "c"

But I want it to match it like :

- 1: "1. "
- 2: "Eccentric Shop Teacher"
- 3: "20M+"
- 4: "Good"
- 5: "EST"

Could any experts with regex help me?

Comment: " 1. Eccentric Shop Teacher 20M+ Good EST 2. Wanwood Crown 18M+ Low WWC 3. Domino Crown 16M+ Great DC 4. Dominus Empyreus 16M+ Great Emp "
.............indent this part!!!

Comment: Are you sure you have that much of tabs/spaces between `Teacher` and `20+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
var regex = /(\d+\.)\s+([a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)*)\s+(\d+M\+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/i;
```

Explanations:

```
(\d+\.)          # first capturing group: one or more digits and a dot
\s+              # spaces

(                # open the second capturing group
  [a-z]+         # one or more letters (a word)
  (?:            # open a non capturing group
    \s[a-z]+     # a space followed by a word
  )*             # close the non capturing group, repeat zero or more times
)                # close the second capturing group

\s+              # one or more spaces
(\d+M\+)         # third capturing group: one or more digits, M, +

\s+
([a-z]+)         # fourth capturing group: a word

\s+
([a-z]+)         # fifth capturing group: a word
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain it to me? Cause I am not very good with regex.